# bottle.py WSGI server stops responding

Tags: wsgi, ubuntu-10.04, bottle

I'm trying to build a simple API with the bottle.py (Bottle v0.11.4) web framework. To 'daemonize' the app on my server (Ubuntu 10.04.4), I'm running the shell

```
nohup python test.py &
```

, where test.py is the following python script:

```
import sys
import bottle
from bottle import route, run, request, response, abort, hook

@hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

@route('/')
def ping():
  return 'Up and running!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run(host=<my_ip>, port=3000)
```

I'm running into the following issue:

This works initially but the server stops responding after some time (~24hours). Unfortunately, the logs don't contain any revealing error messages.

The only way I have been able to reproduce the issue is when I try to run a second script on my Ubuntu server that creates another server listening to a different port (ie.: exactly the same script as above but port=3001). If I send a request to the newly created server, I also do not get a response and the connection eventually times out.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I'm new to this, so if there's something fundamentally wrong with this approach, any links to reference guides would also be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the server isn't sleeping.
If it is, try enabling Wake On LAN http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=234588